# Modifying a program to read dictionary items from a file and write the inverted dictionary to a file

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I keeping pumping my head through walls with this code. The file that gets generated is empty. Can you please examine my code and tell me what I might be doing wrong ?

I have a simple text saved in my documents as such:

Garcia,BCS,female,twentyone
Grzechnik,BBA,male,thirty
Kerrou,BCS,male,twentynine
Saiki,BSA,male,twentyone
Kardashian,AAS,female,twentyone
Jackson,AAS,female,twentyfive

My code below does in fact generate a new file, but the file doesn't contain the inverted dictionary, it just returns a blank file.

I appreciate your guys' help!

```
# opening the input file
f1 = open('C:\\Users\\Dr. Younes\\OneDrive\\Documents\\student_profiles.txt', 'r')

# Initializing the original dictionary
list_dict = {}

for line in f1:
    line_items = line.strip().split(',')   # Splitting the line into elements by comma

    if line_items[0] in list_dict:       # Writing to dictionary if key is already present
        list_dict[line_items[0]].append(line_items[1])
        list_dict[line_items[0]].append(line_items[2])
        list_dict[line_items[0]].append(line_items[3])

    else:                        # Writing to dictionary if key is not present
    list_dict[line_items[0]] = [line_items[1], line_items[2], line_items[3]]

# Closing the input file as good practice
f1.close()

# Printing the original dictionary
print("Original")
for k, v in list_dict.items():
   print("{}: {}".format(k, v))
print("")

# Reading the each key in original dictionary
def invert_dict(d):
    inverse = dict()
    for key in d:            # reading each value in values of that key
        val = d[key]
        for element in val:
            if element not in inverse:
                inverse[element] = [key]     # Writing to inverted dictionary if key is not present

            else:
                inverse[element].append(key)  # Appending to inverted dictionary if key is present
    return inverse

# Making the inverted dictionary by calling the functions
inverseDict = invert_dict(list_dict)

# Printing inverted dictionary
print("Inverted")

for k, v in inverseDict.items():
    print("{}: {}".format(k, v))

# opening the my_inverted_dict.txt file in write mode
f2 = open('my_inverted_dict.txt', 'w')

# Writing one line at a time
for i in inverseDict:
    line = i + ',' + ','.join(inverseDict[i])
    f2.write(line)
    f2.write('\n')

# Closing the file as good practice
f2.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried running through a debugger? Printing ot some intermediate steps? Anything?

Comment: I haven't tried to run through a debugger yet actually

Comment: You should always do that *before* asking. Make a habit of exhausting all avenues available to you before wasting the precious time of others.

Comment: I receive this error: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dr. Younes\OneDrive\Documents\my_program.py", line 16, in <module>
    list_dict[line_items[0]] = [line_items[1], line_items[2], line_items[3]]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I added four spaces at the beginning of line 16 and ran your script, got an output file with six lines.

Comment: thank you burkay, I will try it now

Comment: I just read the error you posted. I'm pretty sure your input file ends with an empty line. Delete that one and you'll be fine. Line 16 tries to access the 2nd, 3rd, 4th tokens of the splitted array, which won't exist in that case.

Comment: Can you send me the code with the indentation since it seems to keep throwing the same error..? Thanks mate

Comment: It's still throws back an empty file burkay. Help please!

Comment: No worries, I will wrap up an answer below :)

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your posted code fails to run, is not minimal, and does not include intermediate tracing attempts.

Comment: Hi Prune, thanks for your feedback, I expect the data in a text file called student_profiles.txt to be converted to a dictionary and then inverted into a new text file with the desired name, the input file contains 6 lines: 

Garcia,BCS,female,twentyone\n Grzechnik,BBA,male,thirty\n 
Kerrou,BCS,male,twentynine\n 
Saiki,BSA,male,twentyone\n 
Kardashian,AAS,female,twentyone\n 
Jackson,AAS,female,twentyfive\n

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the indentation at line 16:

```
# opening the input file
f1 = open('test.txt', 'r')

# Initializing the original dictionary
list_dict = {}

for line in f1:
    line_items = line.strip().split(',')   # Splitting the line into elements by comma

    if line_items[0] in list_dict:       # Writing to dictionary if key is already present
        list_dict[line_items[0]].append(line_items[1])
        list_dict[line_items[0]].append(line_items[2])
        list_dict[line_items[0]].append(line_items[3])

    else:                        # Writing to dictionary if key is not present
        list_dict[line_items[0]] = [line_items[1], line_items[2], line_items[3]]

# Closing the input file as good practice
f1.close()

# Printing the original dictionary
print("Original")
for k, v in list_dict.items():
   print("{}: {}".format(k, v))
print("")

# Reading the each key in original dictionary
def invert_dict(d):
    inverse = dict()
    for key in d:            # reading each value in values of that key
        val = d[key]
        for element in val:
            if element not in inverse:
                inverse[element] = [key]     # Writing to inverted dictionary if key is not present

            else:
                inverse[element].append(key)  # Appending to inverted dictionary if key is present
    return inverse

# Making the inverted dictionary by calling the functions
inverseDict = invert_dict(list_dict)

# Printing inverted dictionary
print("Inverted")

for k, v in inverseDict.items():
    print("{}: {}".format(k, v))

# opening the my_inverted_dict.txt file in write mode
f2 = open('my_inverted_dict.txt', 'w')

# Writing one line at a time
for i in inverseDict:
    line = i + ',' + ','.join(inverseDict[i])
    f2.write(line)
    f2.write('\n')

# Closing the file as good practice
f2.close()
```

Created a text file with this content:

```
Garcia,BCS,female,twentyone Grzechnik,BBA,male,thirty Kerrou,BCS,male,twentynine
Saiki,BSA,male,twentyone Kardashian,AAS,female,twentyone Jackson,AAS,female,twentyfive
```

Ran the script and got below content in the output file:

```
BCS,Garcia
female,Garcia
twentyone Grzechnik,Garcia
BSA,Saiki
male,Saiki
twentyone Kardashian,Saiki
```

Comment: I still receive the same error on my end, which is weird

Comment: I put it together at https://onlinegdb.com/B1vpD7rRw